# How do I make a turtle reset when it hits a circle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The code has no errors, I just need to add something in.
Here is the code for the turtle:

```
#move is the spaceship


move = turtle.Turtle()

showturtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
move.setposition(-500,0)
move.pencolor('cyan')
move.fillcolor("blue")
move.penup()
move.speed()
move.shapesize(3,3,3)



def k1():
   move.forward(25)

     

def k2():
   move.left(30)


def k3():
   move.right(30)

   
def k4():
   move.backward(15)





wn.onkey(k1, "Up")
wn.onkey(k2, "Left")
wn.onkey(k3, "Right")
wn.onkey(k4, "Down")
```

And here is the circle:

```
asteroid = Turtle()

if move.distance(asteroid)<5:
    move.goto(0,0)
asteroid.pencolor('grey')
asteroid.fillcolor('grey')
asteroid.begin_fill()
asteroid.hideturtle()
asteroid.penup()
asteroid.speed(15)
asteroid.setposition(randint(-400,400), randint(-400,400))
asteroid.pendown()
asteroid.circle(35)
asteroid.end_fill()
```

I need the program to restart the game when 'move' hits 'asteroid'.
The program works fine but I just need to add to it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the position of your objects and compare them regularly.

The function `.pos` gives you the current position of your object.

You should make a loop where you check if the positions of your objects are the same.

```
if move.pos() == asteroid.pos():
   print("Collision!")
```

You'll have to add the size of your objects to these values too (e.g. `move_size = move.pos() + your_shape_size` sorry I've never worked with turtle), because two edges might hit each other, which is a collision too.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that there are a lot of circles. Would you know how to make that work?

Comment: What do you mean by a lot of circles? Do the ship and the asteroid consist of circles or are there other circles which should not report a collision?

Comment: So the ship is the actual turtle. There are many asteroids(circles) scattered around the canvas.

Comment: Alright, so basically you need to compare the position of your turtle/ship with the position of every asteroid, because you want to track any collision.